# oprofile on Linux running in a virtual machine

Tags: profiling, g++, performance, oprofile

I'm running a Linux Ubuntu 10.4 VM using VirtualBox. I'm trying to use oprofile to profile some application in the virtual machine. I've installed oprofile 0.9.6 but I cannot get it to work. When I try to start I get the following error:

```
opcontrol --start
/usr/local/bin/opcontrol: line 323: /usr/local/bin/ophelp: cannot execute binary file
/usr/local/bin/opcontrol: line 1483: /usr/local/bin/oprofiled: cannot execute binary file
Couldn't start oprofiled.
Check the log file "/var/lib/oprofile/samples/oprofiled.log" and kernel syslog
```

As I'm not sure if VirtualBox could provide access to the performance counters (I'm in doubt here so if you have any pointers it would be great) I defaulted oprofile to the timer interrupt like so:

```
opcontrol --deinit
/usr/local/bin/opcontrol: line 323: /usr/local/bin/ophelp: cannot execute binary file
Unloading oprofile module
root@dev-ubuntu-10:/usr/local/bin# /sbin/modprobe oprofile timer=1
root@dev-ubuntu-10:/usr/local/bin# opcontrol --init
```

But still not working and I'm getting the same error. Is it even possible to run oprofile in a VM?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried something similar in the past, only with VMware Fusion and a different profiler, and run into the same problem. It seems that access to the performance registers and other low level stuff that profilers need is just not feasible in a VM. You'll need a real machine for profiling, I'm afraid.

Comment: I was expecting to not have access to the performance counters but I thought at least the timer interrupt should be available to the "virtualized" system.

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
/usr/local/bin/ophelp: cannot execute binary file
```

usually means that you are attempting to execute an `x86_64` binary on a 32-bit kernel.

What do `file usr/local/bin/ophelp` and `uname -a` print?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years ago I had some problem running oprofile inside vmware. I wrote my little experience on this post http://blogs.epfl.ch/category/3239

Comment: So, in your solution, there are no any hardware counters available for guest system? And the system timer was used to periodically generate sampling events.

Comment: correct, the vm filters out those registers. I don't think it's an easy thing to do (i.e. multiplex those registers).

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't there anymore. But it is at https://web.archive.org/web/20161104115952/https://blogs.epfl.ch/category/3239. Of course, if you have a more up-to-date URL, that would be better

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing older versions like [oprofile-0.9.7](http://sourceforge.net/projects/oprofile/files/oprofile/oprofile-0.9.7/oprofile-0.9.7.tar.gz/download?use_mirror=kaz)

extract it anywhere then follow steps:

```
install it by >  1 ./configure 2. make 3. make install
```

Then try using it it works fine you might want to turn on virtual CPU counters in VMWARE and disable nmi_watchdog registers in linux as they might be used by other profilers.

Answer (score 0):

use of HPC(hardware performance counters) requires hardware supprot, try to install cpuid in vbox, you will see

```
 Architecture Performance Monitoring Features (0xa/ebx):
  core cycle event not available           = false
  instruction retired event not available  = false
  reference cycles event not available     = false
  last-level cache ref event not available = false
  last-level cache miss event not avail    = false
  branch inst retired event not available  = false
  branch mispred retired event not avail   = false
```

Architecture Performance Monitoring Features (0xa/edx):
      number of fixed counters    = 0x0 (0)
      bit width of fixed counters = 0x0 (0)

It seems that just Vmware and KVM can emulate PMU unit, and not the VBOX